# HTTP Error: HTTP authentication failed nusoap php API

Tags: php, authentication, soap

Access link (http://mef.com.pk/test/samples/test.php)

```
require_once('../lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client("http://miuc.com.pk/test/samples/test1.php");
$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) { echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>"; }
$result = $client->call("getProd", array("category" => "books"));
if ($client->fault) {
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
else {
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<h2>Books</h2><pre>";
        echo $result;
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

now come to another link that is calling. (http://miuc.com.pk/test/samples/test1.php)

**code**

```
require_once('../lib/nusoap.php');
function getProd($category) {
    if ($category == "books") {
        return join(",", array(
            "The WordPress Anthology",
            "Build Your Own Website the Right Way"));
    }
    else {
            return "No products listed under that category";
    }
}

$server = new soap_server();
$server->register("getProd");
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

now when running http://mef.com.pk/test/samples/test.php

**Error**

> HTTP Error: HTTP authentication failed

Please see the code above. I have tried many changes but am still receiving an error. I appreciate any help get from the other server using soap API.

Comment: miuc.com have windows server where as mef.com.pk have Linux based server

Comment: Call the `setCredentials` method of the client to provide the authentication data …?